# Highlighting columns in a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I am highlighting alternate columns in the table using jquery

```
$("table.Table22 tr td:nth-child(even)").css("background","blue");
```

However I have another `<table>` inside a `<tr>` as the last row. How can I avoid highlighting columns of tables that are inside `<tr>` ?

Comment: Isn't td:even sufficient rather than using nth-child?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qualify it with the `>` descendant selector:

```
$("table.Table22 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(even)").css("background","blue");
```

You need the `tbody` qualifier too, as browsers automatically insert a `tbody` **whether you have it in your markup or not**.

*Edit*: woops. Thanks Annan.

*Edit 2*: stressed tbody.

Comment: I think you missed out one child selector? you will need to make it "table.Table22 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(even)"

Comment: How can I do this without using tbody?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but perhaps: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not#expr

```
$("table.Table22 tr td:nth-child(even)").not("table.Table22 tr td table").css("background","blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I used to do nested checkbox highlighting within a table.  I needed to be able to do a "check all/uncheck all" but only within at a single level within the nesting; that is, I didn't want child elements getting selected as well.

```
var parentTable = $(this).parents("table:first");
var exclusions = parentTable.find("table :checkbox.select");
var checkboxes = parentTable.find(":checkbox.select").not(exclusions);
```

I'd get the first table above the current one I was in, get all the checkboxes *below* this newly found parent table, then exclude them from the complete list of checkboxes I could find.  Basically, I was finding every checkbox, but then excluding any child checkboxes I found.

The same could be adapted in your case; replace the checkbox selection with columns instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the advantages of html ?

Instead of

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try

```
<table>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
       <td>
       ...
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      ...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use the `<thead>` tag too to manipulate headers.

And now you can call the selector on

```
$("table.Table22 tbody tr td:nth-child(even)").css("background","blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you test the following?

```
$("table.Table22 tr td:nth-child(even):not(:last-child)").css("background","blue")
```

Comment: I am sorry I have no more clues :(

Answer (score 0):

This page defines a nice function for selecting a column
http://programanddesign.com/js/jquery-select-table-column-or-row/