# How to highligh the row and column of a table when over a cell using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table 10x10 in html
if I add a function for each td hover, 
how can I get the cell column and row index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, there may be a better way of doing things than trying to find the exact cell location, but if you do need it this should work:

```
$("td").hover(function() {
    var columnIndex = $(this).attr("cellIndex");
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().attr("rowIndex"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to know the column and row index to apply a hover effect, you can simply use the hover function

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout

Answer (score 0):

Haave a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143614/jquery-highlighting-selected-columns-only-in-a-table/1143631#1143631). If you're implementing it yourself then to get row highlighting, you would just either use the pseudo css class `:hover` or jump to closest parent `<tr>` and apply a css class to background color the children `<td>`.

To answer how you get the column and row indexes, use the jQuery .index() command