# Add and remove class on hover with selecting multiple td classes?

Tags: jquery, hover

Could someone help me my website is: [zenart website](http://zenartwebdesigncompany.co.uk/).
What should happen is to add a class of highlight on hover to every column of the table. I have added the same class to every td in each corresponding to make the columns.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
var a = $

a('.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5').hover(
   function(){ a(this).addClass('highlight') },
   function(){ a(this).removeClass('highlight') })  
});
```

Comment: Check this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143614/jquery-highlighting-selected-columns-only-in-a-table

Comment: what error does it throw??

Comment: On the website, the class names are `.1column, .2column...`, not `.column1, .column2,`. You're better off giving your table an id and using `$.('#tableId td')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. You have to extract the name of the class from all the classes and see which class `xcolumn` is currently selected. And then apply style to that class.

```
$(".1column, .2column, .3column, .4column, .5column").hover(
        function () {
            var classes = $(this).attr('class');
            var n = classes.indexOf("column");
            var className = "." + classes.substring((n-1),(n+7));
            $(className).addClass("highlight");
        },
        function () {
            var classes = $(this).attr('class');
            var n = classes.indexOf("column");
            var className = "." + classes.substring((n-1),(n+7));
            $(className).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    );
```

Comment: I see that you changed the name of the class to add from "highlight" to "hover". Please change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i see your classname is `1column` and not `column1`.. so the selector should be

```
 a('.1column, .2column, .3column, .4column, .5column').hover({....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[class*=column]").hover( function() {
```

Specifying each and every element can be difficult. You can `*=` for matching that element has class with `column`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one:

```
$('nav li').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('highlight');
},function(){
   $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```