# JQuery Calcuation - sum all the textboxes in a table column

Tags: jquery

I want to write a selector that gets me all the textboxes in a table column.  So I can use this with Jquery Calculation to get a 'sum' box.  I've written something based off this: [Highlighting columns in a table with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494362/highlighting-columns-in-a-table-with-jquery)

Here's how far I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/Px78h/1/

The page loads, and I see my totals in the `totalSum` box.  But updating any of the textboxes in the column seems to cause it to sum ALL the textboxes.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**: here's the 'end game' of what I was trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Px78h/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not include `totalSum` input:

```
$("table. tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > input[name!='totalSum']").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");
```

Answer (score 5):

You were including the `totalSum` field in your calcluation. Try

```
$("table tr > td:nth-child(1) > input:not(#totalSum)").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");
```

Either that or you make the `totalSum` not an `<input>` itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/Px78h/2/